# How to chain scopes with ransack queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ransack

A user submits a ransack query for finding `employers`.  I want to first use a `scope` to filter down the records in the `employers` table, and then I want to run the ransack query on that `activerecord::relation` object returned from that `scope`.

Specifically in that order.  It is important that the `scope` is run first because it returns only a select number of records which the ransack query can then further filter down.  In my situation, running the ransack query first and then running the `scope` query on the return runs very slow because the ransack query may return many many records.

This sounds like the job of chaining queries together.  I know how to chain regular scopes together:

```
# example
# `active`, `from_department_stores`, and `small_company` are all scopes
@employers = Employer.active.from_department_stores.small_company
```

But I do not know how to chain ransack queries onto scopes, and do it in a manner where the scope is run first.

Code:

```
@q = Employer.ransack(params[:q])
# Pretty sure this will not work, but hopefully it provides a good idea
# of what I am trying to do
@employers = Employer.active.@q.result
```

[Ransack Documentation](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work for you.Thanks

```
@employers = Employer.active.ransack(params[:q]).result
```